# RouterLink in storybook?

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-routerlink

I'm trying to add my component to Storybook and its throwing an error related to RouterLink and it not been part  of Ionic components.

```
 Error: Template parse errors:
 Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-card'.
 1. If 'ion-card' is an Angular component and it has 'routerLink' input, 
 then verify that it is part of this module.
 2. If 'ion-card' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to 
 the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the 
 '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("<ion-app>
```

I am able to import any elements which don't use routerLink however any that do throw this error unless i remove it. How do i add it to Storybook as it shouldn't be that hard I'd have had thought?

My code within Storybook is the following:

```
 .add('Whole feed', () => (
    {
      template:
        `
        <ion-card class="ion-no-margin feedCard" [routerLink]="['./', feedItem.id]">
        <!-- loop though all recipies in recipies.page.ts module.-->
        <ion-img class="feedCard__img" [src]="feedItem.imageUrl"></ion-img><!-- [isPropertybinding] in this context-->
        <div class="feedCard__img--circles">
          <ion-icon name="radio-button-off"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon name="radio-button-off"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon name="radio-button-off"></ion-icon>
        </div>
      </ion-card>
      <div class="feedCard__label">
        <ion-label> {{ feedItem.title }} </ion-label>
        <!-- string interprelation -->
        <ion-label><strong> {{ feedItem.distance }}km </strong></ion-label> <!-- string interprelation -->
      </div>
      `,
              props: {
           },
         }))
```

Other elements are working and Ionic supports fine as as long as i remove any of the bits it doesn't like it works.

How can i include RouterLink into Storybook or tell it to ignore the problem? I dont need the links to work, just to be able to display the component.

My app.modules.ts file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Can you show us your `app.module.ts` ?

Comment: I've added it :)

Answer (score -1):

In order to use `routerLink`, you need to add `RouterModule` to every `@NgModule()`  which uses your component in which `routerLink` is used.

Assuming that your component is only used in AppModule,You need to add `RouterModule` to the imports of your `AppModule`

You code will be like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: That didn't solve it. When i restored [routerLink] it started throwing the same error as before. I had solved it temporarily by removing it entirely though its not a good long term solution.